# How send a value to a model from select (multiselect) MVC RAZOR

Tags: html, asp.net, razor, model-view-controller

How i can send value to model?
I have add.cshtml

```
 @model User
        <select class="selectpicker" id="selectRoles" name="selectRoles" data-style="select-with-transition" multiple="" title="Choose role" data-size="7" tabindex="-98">
                                @foreach (var role in ViewData["Roles"] as IEnumerable<IdentityRole>)
                                {
                                    <option value="@role.Id">@role.Name</option>
                                }
                            </select>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save user</button>
```

In ViewData["Roles"] - list role [{id, name}];

After click button, i want send selected items to a model User in ICollection Roles;

Model user:

```
public class UserViewModel
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Login { get; set; }
        public ICollection<RoleViewModel> Roles { get; set; }
    }
```

In controller method POST

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Add(User user)
```

Comment: please show RoleViewModel model

Comment: why dont you use listboxfor?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC Model Binding With ListBoxFor & DropDownListFor Helpers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19143126/asp-net-mvc-model-binding-with-listboxfor-dropdownlistfor-helpers)

Comment: public class RoleViewModel
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Your model does not even have a property named `selectRoles`. And your `public ICollection<RoleViewModel> Roles { get; set; }` property is pointless. A `<select multiple>` posts back and array of simple values. It would bind to `public IEnumerable<int> SelectRoles { get; set; }`